# Install GVIM on Amazon AMI Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vim, amazon-ami

Does anyone able to run GVIM on Amazon AMI Linux?  The base & epel repositories both don't have gvim prebuilt.  I tried to build gvim myself but ./configure couldn't find the necessary dependency.

I wonder if there is any yum repository would help getting GVIM working.

Comment: Maybe you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136127/how-to-use-gvim-to-edit-a-remote-file

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install vim-X11 vim-common vim-enhanced vim-minimal
```

Comment: vim-x11 is not available in the repository

Comment: I think this one should solve your problem here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095867/how-can-i-use-local-vim-setting-on-aws-server

Comment: but if I am editing a few hundred MB files, this will generate too much overhead in editing locally.  It's better to editor remotely in such case